# Laravel 5: Overwriting/combining package configs with defaults

Tags: php, laravel, config

I am creating a package which uses API calls which I need to protect with auth middleware. I am looking at using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport) to accomplish this.

I am developing this *as a package*, ergo, I want to keep everything as unobtrusive as possible from the primary Laravel installation.

The issue I'm facing is in setting the relevant configuration files. Namely, in `config/auth.php` I need to set

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport', // change "token" -> "passport"
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Now, how can I do this in a way that will only apply to my package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your package to use a different set of configurations, independent of what the installation might have defined, you could temporarily change the configuration before making your calls. In this case I'd wrap it up in a reusable class method:

```
use Config;

class ApiCalls {

    public static function usingPackageConfig(callable $callback)
    {
        // Fetch original config.
        $originalDriver = Config::get('auth.api.driver');

        // Set custom config.
        Config::set('auth.api.driver', 'passport');

        // Execute callback with custom config.
        $result = $callback();

        // Reset config.
        Config::set('auth.api.driver', $originalDriver);

        return $result;
    }

}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
ApiCalls::usingPackageConfig(function() {
    // Make your Passport call here and it will use your package's configuration.
});
```